# $\psi_2$ marginals of the permutahedron?

Tags: pr.probability, convex-geometry, convex-polytopes

Let $K$ be a convex body.
I in particular care about the [permutahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron).
I will view this as being the convex hull of all coordinate-wise permutations of the vector

$$v = \frac{1}{2n+2}(-n, -n+2,\dots, n-2, n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}.$$

This is the Voronoi cell of the $A_{n}^*$ root lattice.

Anyway, I am interested in the concentration properties of $\vec x\sim\mathsf{Unif}(K)$, or in particular in bounding the mgf of $\langle \vec x, \theta\rangle$ for $\lVert \theta\rVert_2 = 1$.
I will say that $\langle \vec x, \theta\rangle$ is $\psi_\alpha$ if it has bounded $\exp(x^\alpha)-1$ Orlicz norm, i.e. $\psi_1$ corresponds to sub-exponential marginals, and $\psi_2$ corresponds to sub-gaussian marginals.

I know that

1. For all $\theta$, $\langle \vec x,\theta\rangle$ is $\psi_1$, and
2. For most (i.e. with high probability with respect to a uniform choice of) $\lVert \theta\rVert_2 = 1$, $\langle \vec x, \theta\rangle$ is $\psi_2$.

I think the first is due to Borell, and the second is the celebrated central limit theorem for convex sets due to Klartag.
This second result is the type I want, but I need results that hold for marginals, or at least all $\theta\in(e_1,\dots,e_{n+1})$ (I am trying to give tail bounds on $\Pr[\lVert X\rVert_\infty \geq \kappa]$).

This leaves me with the following questions

1. Can one improve the above estimate for $K$, perhaps by leveraging some "niceness" of it (i.e. it is a zonotope, or has small $O(n\log n)$ extension complexity more generally),
2. Can one improve the above estimate for $K$ for some smaller subset of $\theta$, say $\theta\in \{e_1,e_2,\dots, e_{n+1})$ a standard basis vector?

My current plan is to try to explicitly compute the matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times O(n\log n)}$ such that $K = M[-1,1]^{O(n\log n)}$.
I could then compute the $\ell_\infty\to\ell_\infty$ operator norm of $M$ to reduce things to the setting of showing $\ell_\infty$ concentration of a uniform variable on $[-1,1]^{O(n\log n)}$, i.e. to a trivial problem.
The issue I am running into is that $M$ seems quite complicated --- it is defined using the AKS sorting network, which is notoriously complex.
I could probably simplify things somewhat (redo the proof of the extension complexity of the permutahedron for a different sorting network, choose one of depth $O((\log n)^2)$ that is concretely simpler, though asymptotically sub-optimal by a logarithmic factor.
This would also have the benefit of potentially giving me better concrete bounds, given the horrible constants implicit in AKS), but before using this admittedly rather convoluted argument, I was curious if there was a direct/simpler argument, given how straightforward the random variable I am trying to bound is.

Note that despite using notation $O(n\log n)$, I do care about particular constants.
I don't necessarily need an optimal constant, but do need to know a tail bound up to an explicitly-known constant.